# How to Debug Global variable in MEL script

Tags: movilizer

I am new to MEL script. I don't know how to debug MEL script like c#. Please help me to debug MEL script. Currently i have one global varible like below.

`$global:employeeList[$local:employeeInfo] = {{"eName":"{2}";"doj":"{1}";"designation":"{3}"}};`

here i want to debug the complete $local:employeeInfo variable info. Please help me on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you cannot debug MEL scripting as an usual application, but you have few ways that you can debug it:

1. Is the most common way. You can use a debug client. In the left side of the debug screen you have all the global, local and temporal variables.
2. Use the `warning` MEL method. With this method, you can log a custom warning message in the Monitoring service of the Movilizer Portal. It will be logged during next synchronization of the Movilizer client
3. You can use the `showDialog` or `showProgress` method in order to show a message in your Movilizer application during the execution. In this message you can print the local array with `printarray` method.

Hope it will be useful for you